# Loosen the condition for maximum principle for harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The maximum principle I am talking about the following version from Conway Complex Analysis:

Let $G$ be a region and let $u$ and $v$ be two bounded continuous real valued functions on $G$ that have the Mean Value Property. If for each point $a$ in the extended boundary $\partial_{\infty}G$ ($\partial_{\infty}G=\partial G$ when $G$ is bounded and $\partial_{\infty}G=\partial G\cup \{\infty\}$ when $G$ is not bounded),

$$\limsup_{z\rightarrow a}u(z)\le \liminf_{z\rightarrow a}v(z)$$
then either $u(z)<v(z)$ for all $z$ in $G$ or $u=v$.

I am wondering whether it is possible to loosen the condition to that $u$ is bounded above and $v$ is bounded below. Based on the proof given by Conway in the text, I think we can do that but I am not very confident.

Notice that we some boundedness assumption is necessary as we can consider the following example.

Let $u(z)=\log|z|$ and $v=2\log |z|$ be harmonic function on $\mathbb{D}\backslash \{0\}$. Then, we have $\limsup_{z\rightarrow a}u(z)=\liminf_{z\rightarrow a}v(z)$ for all $a\in \partial(\mathbb{D}\backslash \{0\})$ but we have $v(z)\le u(z)$

Comment: the result follows precisely as in Conway since you need to prove that the hypothesis implies $\limsup_{z\rightarrow a}(u(z)-v(z)) \le 0$ and the manipulations in Conway use only the superior boundness of $u, -v$

Comment: @Conrad Thank you.